# Unity Gamecenter Login

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, authentication, game-center

Get a problem with Login via Gamecenter. When new users launch a game, they don't login in, they need to go in setting and open Gamecenter, then authentication is successful. Have code like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.GameCenter;

public class DoLogin: MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
        GameCenterPlatform.ShowDefaultAchievementCompletionBanner(true);
        Social.localUser.Authenticate(success => {
            if (success)
                Debug.Log("success");
            else
                Debug.Log("Failed to authenticate");
        });
    }
}
```

Capability with gamecenter in XCODE was turned on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Game center is off from settings, you do need to turn it on and sign in from there first. After that if it's your first go at the app with the user name, it should show you a login screen.

In fact, check this out: https://www.imore.com/game-center-help . Apple curbed Game Center a lot since iOS 10.

Comment: I know that I need to go in settings and etc, but what i should do to make login via GameCenter for users. They don't know about this.

Comment: In my last company we made it a mandate do these steps:

- Let the users tap on Game Center icon in your game to sign in. 

- If they are not signed in, show them a simple popup saying they need to activate it from the settings first.

In fact if I am not wrong Apple gave us this suggestion, or at least approved of it. My last was a pretty decently big company with professional contacts in Apple and Google.